# Python numpy: create 2d array of values based on coordinates and plot with pcolormesh, heatplolt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have arrays with Latitude (Lat) and an Lonitude, which is both a 1D array with the shape of 5.
Then I have another array with the value C, this is also a 1D array, with the shape of 5. I would like to plot the hole thing with pcolormesh at the end, so a kind of heatmap plot!

Here is the corresponding code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [13]:

# Data
Lat = np.array([-65.62282562, -65.62266541, -65.62241364, -65.62398529, -65.62410736])
Lon = np.array([145.28251648, 145.38883972, 145.49528503, 121.4509201, 121.55738068, 121.66372681])
C = np.array([0., 0.5, 2, 3, 0])


# Plot
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, C)
```

Then I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-164126d430da> in <module>()
      1 # Plot
----> 2 plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, C)

/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in pcolormesh(*args, **kwargs)
   3091         ax.hold(hold)
   3092     try:
-> 3093         ret = ax.pcolormesh(*args, **kwargs)
   3094     finally:
   3095         ax.hold(washold)

/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in pcolormesh(self, *args, **kwargs)
   5393         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   5394 
-> 5395         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   5396         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   5397 

/home/unix/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in _pcolorargs(funcname, *args, **kw)
   4993         if len(args) == 3:
   4994             X, Y, C = [np.asanyarray(a) for a in args]
-> 4995             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   4996         else:
   4997             raise TypeError(

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So would like to give each X-Y-pair one C value, so there are 5 XY pairs, and 5 C values. In theory it should be no problem, but I really can not find a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, one logical and one when you call `pcolormesh`:

The first is that `C` and `Lat` contain 5 values but `Lon` contains 6 values. That means you don't have 5 XY values and 5 C values, so that's something you should work out.

But it's possible to create a pcolormesh with several distinct coordinates if you expand your coordinates correctly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

# Data
Lat = np.array([-65.62282562, -65.62266541, -65.62241364, -65.62398529, -65.62410736])
Lon = np.array([145.28251648, 145.38883972, 145.49528503, 121.4509201, 121.55738068])
C = np.array([0., 0.5, 2, 3, 0])

# Plot
plt.pcolormesh(np.expand_dims(Lat, 0), np.expand_dims(Lon, 1), C*np.eye(5))
```

The `expand_dims` will make the dimensions correctly broadcast against each other and the `np.eye` makes sure that the correct values will have the values you assigned in `C` and all other coordinates will be zero.

But the output probably won't look good because that's a really sparse coordinate frame.

There are other alternative to `pcolormesh`, especially weighted histograms could be of interest or contours:

```
Lat = np.random.normal(-65, 2, 50000)
Lon = np.random.normal(130, 5, 50000)
C = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50000)

plt.figure()
plt.hexbin(Lat, Lon, C=C, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
```

[image]

Comment: yes I am sorry the Lon should also contain only 5 values! The "sparse coordinate system" is because my real example has a lot more Lat and Lon Values and the corresponding C values (7933 values). So I have the Lat-values from (-65.62282562 to -65.62416077), and I have the Lon-values from (145.28251648 to 121.66372681), which both have the shape of (7933). --> So the "sparse coordinate system" was a kind of bad copying the original array, sorry!

Comment: Your provided example works for my data with the (7933 values) with pcolormesh, but it takes a long time! Are there eventually other, methods that it does not take that long?

Comment: I've included an example of `hexbin` in the answer. If you want fast images you probably need to bin your values.

Comment: Thank you, I did the bins with pcolormesh, with a range of about 200 values, and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

`pcolormesh` is for plotting meshes. Meshes are grids of values (for all three of `lat`, `lon`, and `C`), and `pcolormesh` will plot lines and quads connecting adjacent values within the grid.

You don't have a mesh (2d), you have at best a polyline (1d). That doesn't contain enough information for a unique heat map.

Comment: So that, means I can not plot it with pcolormesh in general? Do I plot it with  polyline or how can I plot it then?

Answer (score 0):

Pcolormesh is intended to be used with 2D variables. If you use np.eye for a variable having large amount of data (as in your real case), you might run into memory problems. 
One can use scatter in the following way to get an outcome like pcolormesh with 1D array which has the same shape as that of two arrays and its values are present at each pair of values of the two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
Lat = np.array([-65.62282562, -65.62266541, -65.62241364, -65.62398529, -65.62410736])
Lon = np.array([145.28251648, 145.38883972, 145.49528503, 121.4509201, 121.55738068])
X=np.array(Lat[:]).tolist()
Y=np.array(Lon[:]).tolist()
C = np.array([0., 0.5, 2, 3, 0])
C = np.array(C[:]).tolist()
# Plot
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=C, s=10)
```